# How do I create a custom Safe contract for my users onboarding to my app?

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk, safe-core

I am developing an application where I want Safe deployed for my app users . The safe will be a 2 of 2 multisig type where one of the owner is the user himself and one is me ( the application ) .

How can I do so ? Which Safe package can help me with this and what all methods do I need to call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Safe{Core} Protocol Kit](https://docs.safe.global/sdk-protocol-kit) to configure and then [deploy](https://docs.safe.global/sdk-protocol-kit#deploy-a-safe) a Safe. All available methods can be found [here](https://docs.safe.global/sdk-protocol-kit/reference/safe).

If you also need to create an Ethereum address for your user, you can also use Safe{Core} [AuthKit](https://docs.safe.global/sdk-auth-kit) to derive one from your user's email.

Note that for deployment you will need to pay for transaction fees if you are not using Gnosis Chain as for now free deployments are only supported on that network.

Hope it helps! Best, Louis

Comment: many many thanks @Louis

Comment: In my usecase , the user will have metamask and can go to Safe wallet to propose transactions , but the application will not have metamask or something like that . Application Private key will be with me only . How can I approve and execute transactions being the application ? Which Safe api can help me with this ?